# Fine grained control over Windows 7 visual effects?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Is there any way to have a fine grained control over the visual desktop effects in Windows 7 ? 
I'm thinking things like animated maximize/minimize, display window content while resizeing, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab > Settings... (under Performance)

[image]