# How to decrease the window opening delay in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to reduce the delay (or turn it completely off) in open/close animation, but keep the minimize/maximize animation turned on?

I used to see animated minimize/maximize. But the opening is too slow in Windows 7. Several programs (like TortoiseGit) are working significantly slower, just because they have to wait all the animation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fine grained control over Windows 7 visual effects?](http://superuser.com/questions/19702/fine-grained-control-over-windows-7-visual-effects)

Comment: I know it's not an exact duplicate of that question, but it's as close as you'll get (to my knowledge).

Comment: Nope. I was in that window before ask, and there's one checkbox for all the windows animation. It is not what I need.